# Как передать выбранное значение выпадающего списка контроллеру в Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Помогите, пожалуйста, передать выбранное значение выпадающего списка (Thymeleaf) в контроллер (Spring).
Имеется контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value="courier/notInTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteUser (@RequestParam String task) {
    System.out.println(task);
    return "redirect:/courier";
}
```

А это список с кнопкой (который не работает, как надо):

```
<div class="taskList" th:object="${task}">
    <select class="form-control" id="courierTasks" name="courierTasks">
        <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
        <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
                th:value="${task}"
                th:text="${task}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <form th:action="@{/courier/notInTime}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden"/>
        <button type="submit">Not in time</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Сам список формируется нормально, проблема в кнопке. Как в неё передать значение, выбранное в списке и отправить в контроллер?

Comment: Думаю, что для передачи данных из списка, он должен находится в пределах тега <form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wolframm спасибо. Да, нужно, чтобы список был внутри тега `form`. Кроме того, у списка должно быть имя, которое принимает контроллер (например, `name="task"`), а в самом контроллере нужно заменить `@RequestParam` на `@Valid`.

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value="courier/notInTime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteUser (@Valid String task) {
    System.out.println(task);
    return "redirect:/courier";
}
```

Презентация:

```
 <form th:action="@{/courier/notInTime}" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" id="task" name="task">
            <option value="">Select task for disable</option>
            <option th:each="task : ${tasks}"
                    th:value="${task}"
                    th:text="${task}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Not in time</button>
 </form>
```